# Validate ViewModel upon button click

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have a ViewModel that implements IDataErrorInfo and a master-detail-view. How can I trigger the vaildation of the current ViewModel item when the user hits the save button in the detail view and not earlier?

Comment: I'd love an answer to this as well

Answer (score 6):

Start by including a flag on your VM, set it initally to false.
In your Button command code (assuming you have bound your button to a command on your VM), turn on the flag before running your validation code.

In the "get" code in the IDataErrorInfo properties, only return a validation error if the flag is set to true, otherwise return an empty string.

Before switching the flag back to false raise a PropertyChangedEvent with an empty string as the property name, this will force the binding system to reevaluate all bindings in the current context, as well as check for errors against IDataErrorInfo.

Answer (score 6):

benPearce has given a great answer.

As he pointed out.

1. have `this[columnName]` return null (even if data is invalid) until you click "Save"
2. within the Save command you need to call `OnPropertyChanged(null)` to let WPF re-evaluete the bindings (and interrogate the indexer)

Instead of using a flag this sample uses a Dictionary to achieve the same result.

---

In the **View**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Surname, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

In the **ViewModel**

```
public string Surname { get; set; }

#region Validation
//http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx
Dictionary<string, string> validationErrors = new Dictionary<string,string>();

void Validate()
{
    validationErrors.Clear();
    if (srtring.IsNullOrWhitespace(Surname)) // Validate Surname 
    {
        validationErrors.Add("Surname", "Surname is mandatory.");
    }

    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/5210633/240835
    // Call OnPropertyChanged(null) to refresh all bindings and have WPF check the this[string columnName] indexer.
    OnPropertyChanged(null);
}

#region IDataErrorInfo Members
public string Error
{
    get 
    {
        if (validationErrors.Count > 0)
        {
            return "Errors found.";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public string this[string columnName]
{
    get 
    {                
        if (validationErrors.ContainsKey(columnName))
        {
            return validationErrors[columnName];
        }
        return null;
    }
}

#endregion
#endregion
public void Save()
{
    Validate();
    if (validationErrors.Count == 0)
    {
        DoSave();
    }
}
```